# My yeast isn't floating at the top of my mead

Tags: yeast, mead, first-time-brewer, pitch

I just made my first ever batch of mead. I used a stronger yeast (a wine yeast) and the package said to let it sit for about 15 minutes in 50ml of warm water. I did that and added the water and yeast mixture to my fermenter which already had the must (correct terminology?) in it. However, the yeast did not just float at the top like it usually does when used dry, instead some was suspended in the must and some even ended up at the bottom.

Will the yeast float back up in a couple days? Will my fermentation be off? Is this batch ruined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes. no. no.

the mead is fine.

put it in a dark place for a year, check on it again in 9 months, maybe.

if you didn't add yeast nutrient, add some in the next month or so.

it's fine.

Comment: Add some yeast nutrient in the next month? Or add more yeast?

Comment: nutrient.  mead doesn't have much in the way of the nutrients that yeast need to grow and be healthy.  actually, on second thought, I'd add some nutrient asap.

Comment: Alright, I'll pick some up this weekend and add some. This is my first time making the mead so I'm not sure which kind of nutrient or how much to put. Could you give me a rough estimate for about 10L of must?

Comment: Wow, you'd leave it in the FV for up to a year... not rack it into a clean air-tight container after a week or 3?